# How does Object.create not allow multiple inheritance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) gives this explanation of inheritance in Javascipt (with the comments showing the prototype chain):

```
var a = {a: 1}; 
// a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var b = Object.create(a);
// b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
console.log(b.a); // 1 (inherited)

var c = Object.create(b);
// c ---> b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var d = Object.create(null);
// d ---> null
console.log(d.hasOwnProperty); 
// undefined, because d doesn't inherit from Object.prototype
```

Here it looks to me like `c` is inheriting from multiple classes. How is this **not** multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is when the parents are on the same level in the hierarchy:

```
c ---> b ---> Object.prototype ---> null
 \---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

In this case, it's simple inheritance from a class `b` which inherits from an other class `a`:

```
c ---> b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

---

*Addendum:* While the effects might seem similar (attributes of `b` will be also "found" in c via lookup in the prototype chain), do note the difference that multiple inheritance would allow `a` and `b` to have entirely different inheritance chains (in fact, inheritance "trees"), which is clearly not the case in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @zerkms, I was just about to add something like that myself.

Comment: I hope my ASCII art isn't too ugly though :-)

Comment: I see. So just to be completely clear, in the question's example, the object is inheriting from other objects higher in the chain, not on the same level?

Comment: @Startec - I'm not sure I follow - that chain is THE inheritance chain, there's no inheriting from outside it by definition, and there's no elements on the same level, because it's a one-by-one chain.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance means inheriting *in parallel* from two or more classes, i.e. having two or more *direct* ancestors. They form a tree.

In your case there's only *one* direct ancestor: b, and a is b's direct ancestor, but indirect of c. They form a linear chain.